# Lag with hyper-v vm

Tags: hyper-v

I have created a Hyper-V VM that is running Windows 10 and I have noticed that it lags a little when scrolling through pages or just rendering simple CSS keyframe animations in the browser.

There's not much noticeable lag anywhere else, but it is super annoying when the browser starts lagging like mentioned above.

**VM Specs:**

- Generation 2
- 4GB Ram
- 6 Virtual Processors (kept throwing more at it to see if it would help... it didn't)

Is there any way to fix this problem with hyper-v (maybe by being able to take full advantage of a GPU) or is it something that is only fixed by using something like VMware or VirtualBox?

**Firefox when running a WebGL benchmark**: [task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTx59.png)

Comment: 4GB of RAM is barely enough for Windows 7, let alone Windows 10. Give the VM more RAM.

Comment: @joeqwerty I assigned 8GB and it is dynamic, it doesn't use all 8GB when looking at it in the hyper-v manager. Right now it is using ~3GB. Animations are still a bit laggy

Comment: I can see 3 things, either the System overall RAM of the hypervisor is weak, the virtual video card driver is not a good match, or it could be how you are attaching to the Win7 VM. If you are attaching from the console interface within the VM, instead of via RDP, that could introduce lag since its the server video ram supporting both the hypervisor and the VM functions at the same time.

Comment: @RowanHawkins How can I check the video card driver? I am connecting to the VM by clicking connect in the hyper-v manager, should I be doing this a different way? The VM is dynamically being assigned ram when it needs it, should I set it to an amount and just let it have all of it at once?

Comment: Stack exchange really isn't designed for troubleshooting however it sounds like you are connecting via the console you should try rdp from another system while not logged into the server console. Personally I use oracle VM VirtualBox if I want the guest to use a window on the local system. If you shut the VM down hyperV should let you adjust settings for the VM guest. Look for something like display or video settings and look for graphics controller type. That is what the os on the guest needs windows 10 drivers to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular VM's are not made for high graphics performance and basically do not use a GPU - at all. The GPU is partially offloaded to the client (RDP can send draw commands), partially done by CPU.

If you want high visual performance with a Hyper-V GPU, that is possible... assuming you have a high bandwidth connection (optimized for local LAN). The term you look for is RemoteFX.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/server-2019-hyper-v-vm-using-gpu/m-p/303761

has instructions. Powershell needed on 2019.

Answer (score 1):

First off, most Virtual servers are not designed for stunning video performance. I wouldn't try running a movie from a VM Guest for instance. That is not what they were designed to do. Nevertheless, when you are viewing the Guest console from within the hypervisor on the same system, your refresh rate is even lower since the VM might send a screen update that you wont see until the local console refreshes.

The best way to view a guest on an Enterprise Hypervisor is using Remote Desktop from another system and being in full screen mode. Then your local system is only displaying from the remote system. Your network speed may affect how things look.

Another potential issue is that standard commercial servers do not have high performing graphics engines to begin with. If you are not using on Chip video which shares regular ram, you are using a very low memory 2D graphics that is just designed for managing a server not day to day interaction with it. We are talking 16MB Video Ram here. Like what a high end 486 from 25 years ago would have.

If you still have poor performance then you can try shutting down the VM and adjusting the Display Memory from the Virtual Machine Guest settings. This is NOT system memory for the guest.

Personally If I want better video performance on a VM, rather than HyperV I use something with a lighter OS lift like Oracle's "Virtual Box" which offers better Video memory allocation through the Guest Settings interface. Virtual Box is designed to run inside a non-server OS and leverages your better desktop video card to do that.

Comment: This is not exactly true - there are ways to make VM's shine, but it involves specia lgraphics cards that can handle that, special licensing and then attach a physical GPU to the machine. You can evem play video games with that - on local LAN, though, because the network usage will go HIGH.

Comment: Yes, but a stock server video card will not have that capability. Most onboard server video have far less than 1G of actual ram associated with them strictly for color space at a high resolution, not for graphics performance.